# Export module class from another module

Tags: javascript, import, ecmascript-6, export

I have a module [`netmap`](https://github.com/serain/netmap.js/blob/master/netmap.js) that exports a default class `NetMap`:

```
export default class NetMap {...}
```

I have another module `helloworld` and I want to export (not as a `default`) the entire `NetMap` class so that another module can access `NetMap` by using:

```
import * as helloworld from 'helloworld'

const x = helloworld.NetMap()
```

Is this possible? What would the `export` of `NetMap` look like in the `helloworld` module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`netmap.js`

```
export default class NetMap {
    ...
}
```

`helloworld.js` (usually called a [*barrel*](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/tips/barrel.html)):

```
import NetMap from './netmap.js';
import Foo from '...';
import ...

export {
    NetMap,
    Foo,
    ...
};
```

Then, in another module:

```
import * as helloworld from './helloworld.js';

const x = new helloworld.NetMap();
```

But I personally prefer to use named imports/exports, so I would do it like this instead:

`netmap.js`

```
export class NetMap {
    ...
}
```

`helloworld.js` (usually called [*barrel*](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/tips/barrel.html)):

```
export { NetMap } from './netmap.js';
export { Foo } from '...';
export { ...
```

Then, in another module:

```
import * as helloworld from './helloworld.js';

const x = new helloworld.NetMap();
```

Or:

```
import { NetMap } from './helloworld.js';

const x = new NetMap();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I can tell what you're trying to do, and it certainly seems possible. But do let me know if I misunderstood.

So you have your netMap file...

```
// netMap.js
class NetMap {
    constructor(a,b) {
        this.a = a
        this.b = b
    }
}

export default NetMap
```

then you have your helloworld file that uses netmap as well as maybe some other things....

```
// helloworld.js
const netMap = require('./netMap')
// import netMap from 'netMap'

const helloWorld = _ => console.log('hello world!')

module.exports = { netMap, helloWorld }
export { netMap, helloWorld }
```

and now you have a third file for which you're going to import all of hello world...

```
// otherModule.js
var helloWorld = require('./helloworld')
// import * as helloWorld from 'helloworld'
const x = new helloWorld.netMap(2,3)

console.log(x.a, x.b)
```